# How to get TGUID from the GUID_POWERSCHEME_PERSONALITY setting?

Tags: delphi, guid, windows-messages

I've been working on wrapping the full [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows Message, and encapsulating it inside of an event driven component. A majority of it is working fine, and I have also further captured all of the [`PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE` setting GUID's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448380(v=vs.85).aspx) - except for one `GUID_POWERSCHEME_PERSONALITY`.

According to the docs, I am supposed to translate the `Data` member to a `TGUID`...

> The active power scheme personality has changed. All power schemes map to one of these personalities. **The Data member is a GUID that indicates the new active power scheme personality**.

The problem is with the data type provided is as follows:

```
Data: packed array[0..0] of UCHAR;
```

How do I acquire a `TGUID` out of this `Data` member?

Here's how I am currently capturing the rest of these settings, upon capturing the `PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE` event...

```
procedure TPowerMonitor.HandlePowerSetting(const Val: PPowerBroadcastSetting);
var
  VDWord: DWORD;
  function IsVal(G: String): Boolean;
  begin
    Result:= Assigned(Val);
    if Result then
      Result:= IsEqualGUID(StringToGUID(G), Val.PowerSetting);
  end;
begin
  if IsVal('{5d3e9a59-e9D5-4b00-a6bd-ff34ff516548}') then begin
    //GUID_ACDC_POWER_SOURCE
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(Self.FOnSourceChange) then
      FOnSourceChange(Self, TPowerSource(VDWord));
  end else
  if IsVal('{a7ad8041-b45a-4cae-87a3-eecbb468a9e1}') then begin
    //GUID_BATTERY_PERCENTAGE_REMAINING
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(Self.FOnBatteryPercent) then
      FOnBatteryPercent(Self, VDWord);
  end else
  if IsVal('{6fe69556-704a-47a0-8f24-c28d936fda47}') then begin
    //GUID_CONSOLE_DISPLAY_STATE
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(FOnConsoleDisplayState) then
      FOnConsoleDisplayState(Self, TPowerDisplayState(VDWord));
  end else
  if IsVal('{786E8A1D-B427-4344-9207-09E70BDCBEA9}') then begin
    //GUID_GLOBAL_USER_PRESENCE
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(FOnGlobalUserPresence) then
      FOnGlobalUserPresence(Self, TPowerUserPresence(VDWord));
  end else
  if IsVal('{515c31d8-f734-163d-a0fd-11a08c91e8f1}') then begin
    //GUID_IDLE_BACKGROUND_TASK
    if Assigned(FOnIdleBackgroundTask) then
      FOnIdleBackgroundTask(Self);
  end else
  if IsVal('{02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea}') then begin
    //GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(FOnMonitorPower) then
      FOnMonitorPower(Self, TPowerDisplayState(VDWord));
  end else
  if IsVal('{E00958C0-C213-4ACE-AC77-FECCED2EEEA5}') then begin
    //GUID_POWER_SAVING_STATUS
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(FOnPowerSavingStatus) then
      FOnPowerSavingStatus(Self, TPowerSavingStatus(VDWord));
  end else
  if IsVal('{245d8541-3943-4422-b025-13A784F679B7}') then begin
    //GUID_POWERSCHEME_PERSONALITY
    //TODO: How to read "Data" as a TGUID?
    //GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS (8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c)
    //GUID_MAX_POWER_SAVINGS (a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a)
    //GUID_TYPICAL_POWER_SAVINGS (381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e)
  end else
  if IsVal('{2B84C20E-AD23-4ddf-93DB-05FFBD7EFCA5}') then begin
    //GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(FOnSessionDisplayState) then
      FOnSessionDisplayState(Self, TPowerDisplayState(VDWord));
  end else
  if IsVal('{3C0F4548-C03F-4c4d-B9F2-237EDE686376}') then begin
    //GUID_SESSION_USER_PRESENCE
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(FOnSessionUserPresence) then
      FOnSessionUserPresence(Self, TPowerUserPresence(VDWord));
  end else
  if IsVal('{98a7f580-01f7-48aa-9c0f-44352c29e5C0}') then begin
    //GUID_SYSTEM_AWAYMODE
    VDWord:= DWORD(Val.Data[0]);
    if Assigned(FOnAwayMode) then
      FOnAwayMode(Self, TPowerAwayMode(VDWord));
  end else begin
    //Unrecognized GUID
    //TODO: Handle error
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `if (Val.DataLength >= SizeOf(TGUID)) and IsEqualGUID(GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS, PGUID(@Val.Data[0])^) then`...

Comment: @ondrej you can usefully omit the [0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented here:

[POWERBROADCAST_SETTING structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372723.aspx)

The struct is what is know as a "variable length structure". The final member is, potentially, longer than actually declared. The `DataLength` member tells you how much data is actually present in the `Data` member. For example, you can read it out with a call to `System.Move()`.

If the payload really is a GUID then check that `DataLength` is the size of a GUID and copy the data into your GUID variable.

```
var
  GUID: TGUID;
.... 
// check that DataLength = SizeOf(TGUID) 
Move(Data, GUID, DataLength);
```

The data for other power scheme GUIDs is typically a `DWORD`, which is handled in an analogous fashion.